# Validate password in form with encrypted password in database using Hash sha-512

Tags: jquery, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

Validate password in form with encrypted password in database using hash SHA-512 what I’m trying to do is specifically for a change password form.

I can validate if the password in form and in database are not encrypted... But I fail to validate that entered password is equal to database password because the entered password is still in normal form, and the pasword inside database is the encrypted one.

I wanted to use jQuery validation function… But stuck with how to solve by encrypting entered password with database before submiting.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Validate(data)
{
  if(data==true)
  {
   //submit the form
  }
  else
  {
   //dont submit the form. Throw an error/alert
   return false;
  }
}

//when the form is submitted
$("#yourForm").submit(function()
{
var p=$("#oldPassword").val();
$.post("validate.php",{oldpass:p},Validate);
});
```

PHP Part (validate.php)

```
<?php

$oldpassword=$_POST['oldpass'];

//encrypt $oldpassword to md5 or anything as per your requirement
//and compare it with the encrypted password available in the database

if($oldpassword==$dbpass)
{
   $status=true;
}
else
{
   $status=false;
}

echo $status;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Validate(data)
```

that is absolutely not what he was asking for ... have you even read his question? Most likely not.

http://jssha.sourceforge.net/

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html

Comment: im a she hehehe...by the way. will respond back soon..thanks for the guidance.